# Show featherlightbox pop up on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm going to be totally honest. I have zero experience in wordpress php coding but I can do simple adjustments using the wordpress admin. Now I'm facing a problem. I used the feather lightbox js. I have a code below which shows the part of the footer.

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) :  ?>

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {


    $.featherlight("#mylightbox");
        //console.log("hi");



    });

</script>

 <?php endif; ?>



 <?php wp_footer(); ?>

 <a href="#" data-featherlight="#mylightbox">Open element in lightbox</a>
 <div id="mylightbox">This div will be opened in a lightbox</div>

 </body>
```

With this the featherlightbo pops up when i clicked the anchor tag. But what i want to do is to have the feather lightbox to open it on page load. As you can see in my code there's a part there says if front_page which has also ready function. It returns an error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'featherlight' of undefined**

Please I need your help anyone.

Thanks.

Comment: load your `featherlight.js` plugin before your `script` where you call `$.featherlight("#mylightbox");`

Comment: How? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Show us your script loading part, or complete page would be better to analyse properly..

Comment: `$` is undefined, which is why you're using `jQuery(document)` instead of `$(document)`. To fix the undefined issue, try changing `$.featherlight` to `jQuery.featherlight`.

Comment: Thanks Magnus. Another question which has connection to this one. How do I hide the div As I can see the div at the bottom of my page.

Comment: Did my suggestion solve your initial issue? To hide a div, use css and give it the property: `display: none`.

Comment: Yes Magnus. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like jQuery isn't defined using the `$`-sign, since `jQuery.(document)` works.

Change `$.featherlight` to `jQuery.featherlight` and it should work.

As you asked in your comment, you can initially hide the div by adding the css property: `display: none` on that div.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="mylightbox">Text to display in box</div>
```

For this popup use the script

```
$.featherlight($('#mylightbox'), {});
```

This will work